# Bash script with the "paths must precede expression" output

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to find all the SQL files that have BOM, using the following bash script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

set -x

printf '\nStart!\n'
caminho="$PWD"
parametros="-type f -name "*.sql""

$(find ${caminho} ${parametros} -exec grep -l $'\xEF\xBB\xBF' {} \;)
```

But I'm always getting this output:

```
find /home/pablo/SQL -name ComBOM.sql ComVirgula.sql SemBOM.sql -exec grep -l $\xEF\xBB\xBF {} ;
find: paths must precede expression: `ComVirgula.sql'
find: possible unquoted pattern after predicate `-name'?
```

There's a lot of questions regarding this problem, which were solved by adding double quotes on the `-name`, but this didn't work for me. And this is also the same thing that the [man](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) says.

Comment: The core mistake here is discussed in [BashFAQ #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). Because you're using an unquoted parameter expansion, the `*.sql` is expanded by the shell, not passed to `find`.

Comment: ...the extra double quotes here just cancel each other out. When you have `"string ""in more quotes"" there"`, the doubled-up quotes around `in more quotes` do nothing: the first one moves the parser from being in a quoted context to an unquoted context, and the second one moves it back to being in a quoted context again.

Comment: And don't put `$( )` around your final command; the behavior from doing that is basically always wrong (results of a command substitution are parsed the same way as results of a parameter expansion, so fully understanding BashFAQ #50 will explain that too).

Comment: `find . -iname  '*.sql' -exec sed -i.back '1s/^\xEF\xBB\xBF//' {} +`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding pairs of unescaped (thus, syntactic) quotes inside a string quoted with the same type of quote characters *does nothing at all*, because those quotes just cancel each other out. Whereas if you *did* escape the quotes, they would be treated as data instead of syntax at expansion time, so the code still wouldn't behave as-desired but with a different error (a situation [BashFAQ #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) goes into detail on).

---

Use an array, not a string, so you can pass your arguments through exactly as-quoted without unwanted globbing.

Instead of:

```
parametros="-type f -name "*.sql""
```

...use instead:

```
parametros=( -type f -name "*.sql" )
```

and then later:

```
find "$PWD" "${parametros[@]}" -exec grep -l $'\xEF\xBB\xBF' {} +
```